# JQuery change event listener working in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I got a web page with a long table to display data. Using JQuery Tablesorter I made the table sortable.

The last column of the page contains checkboxes (with the class `chk`), to allow the user to select multiple entries. In the table header there is also a checkbox (with the id `checkall` and no class). By clicking this checkbox, the values of all to other checkboxes should flip. As the page needs some time to load fully, I am using the `$(window).load()` function instead of `$(document).ready()`.

I got the following JavaScript code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#checkall').change(function() {
        if ($('#checkall').is(":checked")) {
            $('.chk').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('.chk').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

This works as expected in Chromium, but not in Firefox. After playing around with the code it seems like the Change-Listener is not even set in Firefox. Nothing that I put into the inner function code is executed on checking the checkbox, while the `$(window).load()` function is executed as expected. Same behavior happens when I add an `click()` handler instead or using `on("change, function(){...})`.

Is this a JQuery bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using JQuery 3.6.0 with JQuery Migrate 1.4.1.

**Update:**

I found out that this seems to be a timing issue / race condition. If I reload the page sometimes, it works in Firefox as well in about 1 of 10 tries. But I have still no idea what the cause is and how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using window.load event instead of document.ready? Your code should work with the latter without problem. window.load will actually wait until everything is loaded including images.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I use window.load on purpose. And no, it doesn't work with document.ready (in this case also not with Chrome).

Comment: Is `#checkall` added _after_ document ready? That could be the issue. In that case, add a click handler at the same time this element is created. If that is not possible/under your control you need to use event delegation. Please respond.

Comment: Nope, it comes with the page itself. The weird thing is that i can access the DOM item within the window.load function, f. e.:  console.log($('#ckeckall').prop('checked')); works fine every time. But adding the click handler in the next line doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses event delegation. You need an element that is present in DOM at the time `document.ready` is fired. Lets say that element is the table. You would write:

```
$(function() {
    $("#the-table").on("click", "#checkall", function() {
        // toggle stuff
    });
});
```

In this case the event handler is bound to the table. It will trap all clicks and, if the originator of the event is the checkbox it will fire the callback.